# My background color seaps to the bottom of the page, and I want my footer color to fill the bottom when not scrolling

Tags: css, background, footer

Here's an example... https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onfxk.jpg

There is not a lot of content on the page, so it's height is small.  The body BG color fills the bottom of the page even past the footer - which ends up looking ridiculous...

How can I make that footer color finish out the page when the content is small (no scroll bar on the user's screen)?  I don't want to make a huge footer permanently for every page, because that would share in the ridiculousness.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you not give the body the same background color as the footer?

Comment: Nope, because it's most of the body color above the footer.  Then i'd run into a similar issue...  The BF color fills the entire browser window, my content is only about 900-1000 px wide, approx.

Comment: If you have `<body><div id='content'>Foo</div><div id='footer'>Foo</div></body>` you could give the body the same bg color, and set a new color for the content background.

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying I think...  let me give it a try, stay tuned.

Comment: Yep, success, thanks. not sure why i didnt think of that... ha

Comment: I've migrated the comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give the body and the footer the same background color, then apply your "body" background color to a wrapper element immediately within the body itself.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Alternative Background Method</title>
    <style>
      body, 
      body > footer {
        background: /* bgcolor */
      }
      #content {
        background: /* original body background color */
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section id="content">
      <!-- main content --->
    </section>
    <footer>
      <!-- footer contents -->
    </footer>
    <!--

      Any visible space between the bottom of the viewport and the 
      footer element will have the same background as the footer
      element itself.

    -->
  </body>
</html>
```